# Install gdal executables

Tags: gdal, software-recommendations, windows-7

Trying to search for gdal executable versions anywhere like the version from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) **before** it was change to wheel but no luck(e.g. GDAL-1.10.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe). Are gdal executables still available? Or was this replaced with wheel?

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac or one of the many flavors of Linux?

Comment: For Windows I have used the binaries and libs from http://www.gisinternals.com/ - developers will need to match to your compiler (version of Visual Studio) - if you don't have a compiler then just pick one, in 32 or 64 bit to match your OS, and download the gdal-XXX-XXXX-core.msi which has the tools in it, then optionally ECW, MRSID and python bindings.

Comment: Was there something special about those particular binaries that aren't in the official distributions?

Comment: If I'm going to use the binaries from the gisinternals.com, there are still libraries needed for gdal to run smoothly that should be installed. While if I'm going to install the executable there is no other libraries needed to install. Is that right?

Comment: They work fine for me with no other libraries (except the correct visual studio runtimes). You only need external libraries if you're building from source.

Answer (score 3):

The [OSGEO4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) setup provides you with GDAL executables in Advanced install, including python bindings for python 2.7 and python 2.7 to run them.

[Gisinternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/) is another source, but not python.

Comment: GisInternals has the python bindings as well but only for a few versions of python. Another good way is to install QGIS which comes with most of the tools - but you can get that from the OSGEO4W installer too!

Comment: You are right, but you need to install python and dependend packages separately. I updated my answer.

Comment: Bindings for python 2.7 suits me, that's what ArcGis uses and it's bad to have more than one python version installed. The OSGEO4W is (arguably) the best method, or at least the best for not getting into trouble as it automatically selects dependencies. I have 3 versions of GDAL installed, all via different methods, each one has its benefits and limitations. GisInternals has the C# wrappers that I haven't seen in OSGEO4W - only important to C# developers that want to use GDAL though; interestingly in C# GDAL is in the OSGeo namespace...

Comment: Gisinternals offers the latest dev builds as well, if you stumble on a bug that has been fixed recently. And all Gisinternal zipped GDAL versions live happily on my hard disk without interfering.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be intimidated by the switch from `.exe` to `.whl`. While the former were installed by double-clicking, the later needs to have a command prompt to install.

## First make sure you have `pip`

Let's take a typical example with Python installed in `C:\Python27`. If you have Python 2.7.9 or later, then you already have `pip` in `C:\Python\Scripts`, otherwise for older versions you need to first [install `pip`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip) from a command prompt, e.g.:

```
cd C:\Users\someone\Downloads
C:\Python27\python.exe pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

But honestly, it is almost simpler to install a more modern version of Python, which all have `pip` included.

## Installing / uninstalling `.whl` with `pip`

After ensuring you have `pip`, it is simple to install downloaded `.whl` files from a command prompt:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip install GDAL‑2.1.2‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
```

And if you need to uninstall:

```
pip uninstall gdal
```

Comment: @user and once you install the wheel, the gdal executables (i.e `gdal_translate.exe` etc) will be in `(python dir)\Lib\site-packages\osgeo`.